# Error Cannot read property '_id' of null?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, mern

It's been all day I tried to update a user profile but I keep getting an error Cannot read property _id null. I can't figure out whats the problem is. I've checked many times backend and frontend, Even checking other's Github repository but I cannot figure out where is the problem. Please help me out with this. Here is my code

And please is there any better way to fetch the user if I don't fetch from userInfo please tell me

if you want to check the full repository here is the GitHub [link](https://github.com/nansmatty/CodeBlog---MERN/tree/master)

Here is what I see in the console (

```
PUT /api/users/profile 500 62.771 ms - 642
```

### Profile.js

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Button, Col, Container, Form, InputGroup, Row } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { toast, ToastContainer } from 'react-toastify';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { updateUserProfile } from '../actions/userActions';
// import { USER_UPDATE_PROFILE_RESET } from '../constant/userConstants';

const Profile = ({ history }) => {
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [pic, setPic] = useState();
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [confirmPassword, setConfirmPassword] = useState('');
  const [picMessage, setPicMessage] = useState();
  const [passwordType, setPasswordType] = useState('password');
  const [passwordType2, setPasswordType2] = useState('password');
  const [showPass, setShowPass] = useState(false);
  const [showPass2, setShowPass2] = useState(false);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  // const userDetails = useSelector((state) => state.userDetails);
  // const { user } = userDetails;

  // console.log(` this is from line 25 ${user}`);

  const userLogin = useSelector((state) => state.userLogin);
  const { userInfo } = userLogin;

  const userUpdateProfile = useSelector((state) => state.userUpdateProfile);
  const { success } = userUpdateProfile;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!userInfo) {
      history.push('/login');
    } else {
      setName(userInfo.name);
      setEmail(userInfo.email);
      setPic(userInfo.pic);
    }

    if (success) {
      return toast.success('Updated Successfully');
    }

    showPass ? setPasswordType('text') : setPasswordType('password');
    showPass2 ? setPasswordType2('text') : setPasswordType2('password');
  }, [showPass, showPass2, dispatch, history, userInfo, success]);

  const postDetails = (pics) => {
    setPicMessage(null);
    if (pics.type === 'image/jpeg' || pics.type === 'image/png') {
      const data = new FormData();
      data.append('file', pics);
      data.append('upload_preset', 'codeblogger_profile_image');
      data.append('cloud_name', 'dhuej17x0');
      fetch('https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/dhuej17x0/image/upload', {
        method: 'post',
        body: data,
      })
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
          setPic(data.secure_url.toString());
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          toast.error(err);
        });
    } else {
      setPicMessage('Please Select an Image');
      toast.error(picMessage);
    }
  };

  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    dispatch(updateUserProfile({ name, email, password, pic }));
  };

  return (
    <div className="profilePage mt-4 py-3">
      <ToastContainer />
      <Container>
        <h2>PROFILE</h2>
        <Row className="profileContainer">
          <Col md={6}>
            <Form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
              <Form.Group controlId="name" className="mb-2">
                <Form.Label>Name</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control
                  type="name"
                  value={name}
                  placeholder="Enter Name"
                  onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
                />
              </Form.Group>
              <Form.Group controlId="email" className="mb-2">
                <Form.Label>Email</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control
                  type="email"
                  value={email}
                  placeholder="Enter email"
                  onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                />
              </Form.Group>
              <Form.Group controlId="password" className="mb-2">
                <Form.Label>New Password</Form.Label>
                <InputGroup>
                  <Form.Control
                    type={passwordType}
                    placeholder="New Password"
                    value={password}
                    onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                  />
                  <InputGroup.Text>
                    <i
                      onClick={() => setShowPass(!showPass)}
                      className={showPass ? 'fas fa-eye-slash' : 'fas fa-eye'}
                      style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }}></i>
                  </InputGroup.Text>
                </InputGroup>
              </Form.Group>
              <Form.Group controlId="confirmPassword" className="mb-2">
                <Form.Label>Confirm Password</Form.Label>
                <InputGroup>
                  <Form.Control
                    type={passwordType2}
                    placeholder="Confirm Password"
                    value={confirmPassword}
                    onChange={(e) => setConfirmPassword(e.target.value)}
                  />
                  <InputGroup.Text>
                    <i
                      onClick={() => setShowPass2(!showPass2)}
                      className={showPass2 ? 'fas fa-eye-slash' : 'fas fa-eye'}
                      style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }}></i>
                  </InputGroup.Text>
                </InputGroup>
              </Form.Group>
              <Form.Group controlId="pic" className="mb-2">
                <Form.Label>Change Profile Picture</Form.Label>
                <Form.File
                  onChange={(e) => postDetails(e.target.files[0])}
                  id="custom-file"
                  type="image/png"
                  custom
                />
              </Form.Group>
              <Button
                type="submit"
                variant="success"
                style={{ letterSpacing: '2px' }}>
                UPDATE
              </Button>
            </Form>
          </Col>
          <Col
            style={{
              display: 'flex',
              alignItems: 'center',
              justifyContent: 'center',
            }}>
            <img src={pic} alt={name} className="profilePic" />
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Profile;
```

### Here is userAction.js file

```
// User Details Action Start===========================================================================

export const getUserDetails = (id) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  try {
    dispatch({
      type: USER_DETAILS_REQUEST,
    });

    const {
      userLogin: { userInfo },
    } = getState();

    const config = {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}`,
      },
    };

    const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/users/${id}`, config);

    dispatch({
      type: USER_DETAILS_SUCCESS,
      payload: data,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    const message =
      error.response && error.response.data.message
        ? error.response.data.message
        : error.message;
    if (message === 'Not authorized, token failed') {
      dispatch(logout());
    }
    dispatch({
      type: USER_DETAILS_FAIL,
      payload: toast.error(message),
    });
  }
};

// User Details Action Complete===========================================================================

// User Profile Details Action Start===========================================================================
export const updateUserProfile = (user) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  try {
    dispatch({
      type: USER_UPDATE_PROFILE_REQUEST,
    });

    const {
      userLogin: { userInfo },
    } = getState();

    const config = {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}`,
      },
    };

    const { data } = await axios.put(`/api/users/profile`, user, config);

    dispatch({
      type: USER_UPDATE_PROFILE_SUCCESS,
      payload: data,
    });
    dispatch({
      type: USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS,
      payload: data,
    });
    localStorage.setItem('userInfo', JSON.stringify(data));
  } catch (error) {
    const message =
      error.response && error.response.data.message
        ? error.response.data.message
        : error.message;
    if (message === 'Not authorized, token failed') {
      dispatch(logout());
    }
    dispatch({
      type: USER_UPDATE_PROFILE_FAIL,
      payload: toast.error(message),
    });
  }
};
// User Profile Details Action Complete===========================================================================
```

### Backend Usercontroller.js file

```
export const updateUserProfile = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const user = await User.findById(req.user._id);

  if (user) {
    user.name = req.body.name || user.name;
    user.email = req.body.email || user.email;
    user.pic = req.body.pic || user.pic;
    if (req.body.password) {
      user.password = req.body.password;
    }

    const updatedUser = await user.save();

    res.json({
      _id: updatedUser._id,
      name: updatedUser.name,
      email: updatedUser.email,
      pic: updateUser.pic,
      isAdmin: updatedUser.isAdmin,
      token: generateToken(updatedUser._id),
    });
  } else {
    res.status(404);
    throw new Error('User not found');
  }
});
```

### routes.js file

```
import express from 'express';
import {
  adminUpdateUserProfile,
  deleteUser,
  getUserById,
  getUserProfile,
  getUsers,
  loginUser,
  registerUser,
  updateUserProfile,
} from '../controller/userController.js';
import { admin, protect } from '../middleware/authMiddleware.js';
const router = express.Router();

router.route('/').post(registerUser).get(protect, admin, getUsers);
router.route('/login').post(loginUser);
router
  .route('/profile')
  .get(protect, getUserProfile)
  .put(protect, updateUserProfile);
router
  .route('/:id')
  .delete(protect, admin, deleteUser)
  .get(protect, admin, getUserById)
  .put(protect, admin, adminUpdateUserProfile);

export default router;
```

Comment: Please add the error stacktrace.

Comment: @Ayzrian I updated the question please check the error in console because of morgan I used I even used react-toastify the toast error was cannot read property _id is null

Comment: Which access in the backend is causing the issue? `req.user._id` or `updatedUser._id`?

Comment: @DrewReese how can i solve this

Comment: It's only in the backend that you try to access _id, so it's obviously there. You can remove all frontend code from the question.

Comment: You could do some console log debugging where you log before and after a suspected problem area, to see where it is breaking You can also try to set breakpoints and step through the code to see values. You could log `req` in the backend.

Comment: From what I can tell, you dispatch `updateUserProfile({ name, email, password, pic })`, and make the PUT request with `{ name, email, password, pic }` as the `user` object passed in the payload. There is no `user` property so when processing the request `req.user` is undefined and throws error when attempting to access `req.user._id`.

Comment: @DrewReese I've tried every possibility logging the error but  I cannot figure the problem

Comment: You're not trying to log the error, you're trying to log variable values in the backend code running on your server. I think if you inject a `_id` into the request body, i.e. `axios.put('/api/users/profile', { ...user, _id: 'test' }, config)` and then instead access `User.findById(req._id)` in `updateUserProfile` it won't blow up on you. If that works then my suspicions were correct and you'll now just need to figure out what `_id` property to send in the requests.

Comment: @DrewReese Well After using your method I got a new error user not found  I used that way `{ ...user, _id: userInfo._id }` I've checked my other repositories the way I did I've done it previously but It looks like only this project is not working